Instagram Login with Facebook Graph API not working
I am creating a web app which uses Facebook graph apis to allow users connect their Facebook and Instagram account to my app so we could automate content posting on their behalf. I have successfully implementend for Facebook but the problem is now with Instagram. After I initiate the auth url I am taken to a page where I'm asked to enter my IG email and password, a popup opens and I enter those details but it doesn't get past there, it just goes back to telling me to "Get started" which is where I started from.
I have been strugling with this problem for days now and would greatly appreciate any help I could get with this.
Another guess I have:
Though I doubt that is the case but could this be happening because I am yet to submit my app for review? If so, why did it work for Facebook?
What I have tried:

I have added and double checked my redirect_uri both on my website and my Facebook developers App
Checked if this issue persists across multiple browsers

What I expect:
After entering my instagram username and password, I should be redirected to my redirect_uri with the access_token and other requested information so I can process them
